# Block Images and Videos of Internet

Tags: windows-7, internet

I'm looking for a way to block some image and video extensions from being shown in all of my internet browsers.

What should I do for this purpose? I have googled but found nothing useful.

Comment: Any specific image and video extensions, and any particular browser? Have you looked at the [FlashBlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flashblock) and [AdBlock plus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adblock_Plus) extensions. I know they are available on the Firefox and Chrome browsers and probably some others.

Answer (score 1):

[Comodo Internet Security](http://www.comodo.com/) has this functionality:

https://help.comodo.com/topic-72-1-451-4811-Blocking-Any-Downloads-of-a-Specific-File-Type.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which browser you are using, but in many browsers you can change the settings. Here in my example I am showing Firefox.

[image: Turning ON/OFF loading images]

Even you may say exclude some web sites. This is only for images, for not showing video you should disable the Adobe Flash player.

I hope that helps!